# Calculate Blending of two Hex int values

Tags: java, graphics, hex, rendering, blending

I want to overlay or more calculate a new color based on two existing.

My colors are stored like this:

```
int color1 = 0xffFF00FF;
int color2 = 0x00FFFFFF;
```

Now as you can tell this is assigned in hex format. I know that these will get transformed into "real" numbers at runtime (or during compile).

These hex "strings" are constructed as you know with the first two symbols after the `0x` represanting the alpha of this color (e.g. `ff` and `00` in this case).

I now want to overlay them so I can get the new color int value. I want to be able to choose which algorithm of overlay (screen, multiply, add, subtract, divide, etc.).

I have done LOTS of research on the Internet, but nothing was telling me how to solve my problem.

I've tried a tons of stuff and did intensive testing and debugging, but I am now at a point where I do not now what to do anymore.

For example:

I tried to do some simple math operation to get the add method etc. done like this:

```
return a + b;
return a - b;
return a * b;
return a / b;
// Even stuff like color burn
return (1 - (1 - a) / b);
```

I got these from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes) but I guess, based on the output that this is based on on the RGBA format `(255/255/255/100)` and not the hex stuff.

Then I tried to convert the hex stuff into RGBA values with the `java.awt.Color` class and binary operations `(a && 0xff)` and much more.

I am literally working on this for days and I don't know exactly how I have done all these things in detail, but I know none of them worked as expected (e.g. the Alpha value was not taken into account.

Maybe I just have a completely wrong starting point or just were looking and working into the wrong direction. Everything so far (also here on SO) wasn't sufficient for my particular situation. Most of the stuff I' ve found were talking about hex-string to int conversation and opposite ;)

Thanks in advance,

Christian

Comment: So, the Hex value for a color is a 6-digit hex number.  The left two digits represent the red values from 00 = 0 to FF = 255.  The middle two digits represent green.  The last two represent blue.  Does this help as a starting point?

Comment: I did know this already. (I used the && operations to split these up) Thanky you anyway.

Comment: Hmm, now that I read your comment to the answer below... I think it would be helpful to see the Hex values for a few examples.  Hex A + Hex B = Hex C, and show us what all the values should be, etc.  I'm not completely clear on what the result should actually look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that you need the weighted average of these values. Something like that:

```
    int color1 = 0xffFF00FF;
    int color2 = 0x00FFFFFF;

    Color c1 = new Color(color1, true);
    Color c2 = new Color(color2, true);
    int a1 = c1.getAlpha();
    int a2 = c2.getAlpha();

    Color result = new Color((c1.getRed() * a1 + c2.getRed() * a2) / (a1 + a2),
            (c1.getGreen() * a1 + c2.getGreen() * a2) / (a1 + a2),
            (c1.getBlue() * a1 + c2.getBlue() * a2) / (a1 + a2),
            (c1.getAlpha() + c2.getAlpha()) / 2);
    System.out.println(c1);
    System.out.println(c2);
    System.out.println(result);
```

That should be fine at least for the 3 colors (rgb). I'm not really sure for the alpha...

Comment: Yeah, but this would calculate the average of these colors and ignoring the alpha channel of both. It' s only taken into account for the final alpha value. In this very example it would still become a lighter pinkish color (FF00FF is pink) even though the white color has an alpha value of 0 (as you pointed out at the end)

Comment: Then how about the weighted sum of these two?       
        Color result = new Color((c1.getRed() * a1 + c2.getRed() * a2) / (a1 + a2),
                (c1.getGreen() * a1 + c2.getGreen() * a2) / (a1 + a2),
                (c1.getBlue() * a1 + c2.getBlue() * a2) / (a1 + a2),
                (c1.getAlpha() + c2.getAlpha()) / 2);

Comment: In fact that should be it: "int red = (int) ((c1.getRed() * a1 + c2.getRed() * a2) / (a1 + a2));" ...

Comment: Yeah this works like a charm for the render mode "average" (only). I just upvoted this answer.

Comment: what if I want to add weight, for example, I want to calculate 30% of color A and 70% of color B?